# Ubuntu 20.4/Foxy - Gazebo/Tiago : no /scan_raw topic

Tags: ros2, beginner, scan, teleop, ros-foxy

Following Rico's book - page 43 - (https://github.com/fmrico/book_ros2)

[Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS / Foxy]

I try to run **Tiago sim** and drive it around a world map with the **teleop launcher**

I run the **simulation** like this

```
cd bookros2_ws/src/
source install/setup.sh
ros2 launch br2_tiago sim.launch.py
```

I run the **teleop** like this

```
cd bookros2_ws/src/
source install/setup.sh
ros2 run teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard --ros-args -r cmd_vel:=key_vel
```

expected:

- the **/scan_raw** topic should be available, **it is not there**
- topic **/head_front_camera/rgb/image_raw** is also missing

checked **so far**:

the **scan appears in the simulation window**, so it is active but **not producing any scan topic**

[image]

[image]

I see this in the **node graph**

[image]

[edit] after fiddling around...

in rqt I added the TF node, base_laser_link seems ok'ish

[image]

I **added a LaserScan topic** and I get this **error**

[image]

probably because there is no such topic

```
phil@ROS2:~/bookros2_ws/src$ ros2 topic echo /scan_raw
WARNING: **topic [/scan_raw] does not appear to be published yet**
Could not determine the type for the passed topic
```

then I **searched** for that **/scan_raw topic**

```
phil@ROS2:~/bookros2_ws/src$ grep -r scan_raw . 
./ThirdParty/pmb2_robot/pmb2_description/urdf/base/base_sensors.urdf.xacro:      <xacro:hokuyo_urg_04lx_ug01_laser name="${name}_laser" parent="${name}" ros_topic="scan_raw" update_rate="10" min_angle="${-110 * deg_to_rad}" max_angle="${110 * deg_to_rad}" >
./ThirdParty/pmb2_robot/pmb2_description/urdf/base/base_sensors.urdf.xacro:      <xacro:sick_tim551_laser name="${name}_laser" parent="${name}" ros_topic="scan_raw" update_rate="10" min_angle="${-110 * deg_to_rad}" max_angle="${110 * deg_to_rad}" >
./ThirdParty/pmb2_robot/pmb2_description/urdf/base/base_sensors.urdf.xacro:      <xacro:sick_tim561_laser name="${name}_laser" parent="${name}" ros_topic="scan_raw" update_rate="10" min_angle="${-110 * deg_to_rad}" max_angle="${110 * deg_to_rad}" >
./ThirdParty/pmb2_robot/pmb2_description/urdf/base/base_sensors.urdf.xacro:      <xacro:sick_tim571_laser name="${name}_laser" parent="${name}" ros_topic="scan_raw" update_rate="10" min_angle="${-110 * deg_to_rad}" max_angle="${110 * deg_to_rad}" >
./ThirdParty/pmb2_robot/pmb2_description/CHANGELOG.rst:* scan_raw is the default laser topic
./ThirdParty/tiago_simulation/tiago_2dnav_gazebo/CHANGELOG.rst:  now uses laser filter to provide scan and scan_raw
./ThirdParty/tiago_simulation/tiago_2dnav_gazebo/CHANGELOG.rst:* now uses laser filter to provide scan and scan_raw
./ThirdParty/pmb2_navigation/pmb2_2dnav/CHANGELOG.rst:* use scan_raw for mapping
./ThirdParty/pmb2_navigation/pmb2_2dnav/params/pmb2_params.yaml:    scan_topic: /scan_raw
./ThirdParty/pmb2_navigation/pmb2_2dnav/params/pmb2_params.yaml:          topic: /scan_raw
./ThirdParty/pmb2_navigation/pmb2_2dnav/params/pmb2_params.yaml:          topic: /scan_raw
./ThirdParty/pmb2_navigation/pmb2_2dnav/params/pmb2_params.yaml:    scan_topic: /scan_raw
./ThirdParty/pmb2_navigation/pmb2_laser_sensors/launch/base_laser.launch:    <remap from="scan"          to="scan_raw"/>
./ThirdParty/pmb2_navigation/pmb2_laser_sensors/launch/hokuyo_laser.launch:    <remap from="scan" to="scan_raw"/>
./ThirdParty/pmb2_navigation/pmb2_laser_sensors/launch/sick-571_laser.launch:    <remap from="scan" to="scan_raw"/>
./ThirdParty/pmb2_navigation/pmb2_laser_sensors/launch/sick-551_laser.launch:    <remap from="scan" to="scan_raw"/>
./ThirdParty/pmb2_navigation/pmb2_laser_sensors/launch/sick-561_laser.launch:    <remap from="scan" to="scan_raw"/>
./ThirdParty/pal_gazebo_worlds/worlds/calibration_room.world:            <topicName>scan_raw</topicName>
./book_ros2/br2_fsm_bumpgo_cpp/launch/bump_and_go.launch.py:                        ('input_scan', '/scan_raw'),
./book_ros2/br2_bt_patrolling/launch/patrolling.launch.py:          ('input_scan', '/scan_raw'),
./book_ros2/br2_navigation/params/mapper_params_online_async.yaml:    scan_topic: /scan_raw
./book_ros2/br2_navigation/params/tiago_nav_params.yaml:    scan_topic: scan_raw
./book_ros2/br2_navigation/params/tiago_nav_params.yaml:          topic: /scan_raw
./book_ros2/br2_navigation/params/tiago_nav_params.yaml:          topic: /scan_raw
./book_ros2/br2_vff_avoidance/launch/avoidance_vff.launch.py:        ('input_scan', '/scan_raw'),
./book_ros2/br2_tf2_detector/launch/detector_basic.launch.py:                          ('input_scan', '/scan_raw')
./book_ros2/br2_tf2_detector/launch/detector_improved.launch.py:                          ('input_scan', '/scan_raw')
./book_ros2/br2_fsm_bumpgo_py/launch/bump_and_go.launch.py:                        ('input_scan', '/scan_raw'),
./book_ros2/code_annex.tex:                        ('input_scan', '/scan_raw'),
./book_ros2/code_annex.tex:                        ('input_scan', '/scan_raw'),
./book_ros2/code_annex.tex:                          ('input_scan', '/scan_raw')
./book_ros2/code_annex.tex:                          ('input_scan', '/scan_raw')
./book_ros2/code_annex.tex:        ('input_scan', '/scan_raw'),
./book_ros2/code_annex.tex:          ('input_scan', '/scan_raw'),
./install/br2_fsm_bumpgo_py/share/br2_fsm_bumpgo_py/launch/bump_and_go.launch.py:                        ('input_scan', '/scan_raw'),
```

I found this

**tiago_2dnav_gazebo/CHANGELOG.rst:  now uses laser filter to provide scan and scan_raw**

- **how do I use filters** ?? why is it not enabled by default ? :
- what could I check ?
- how to **activate a /scan_row topic** ?

---

thanks for your help

...and let me know if you need more information's

[edit]

```
ros2 topic list

/clock
/diagnostics
/dynamic_joint_states
/head_controller/joint_trajectory
/head_controller/state
/joint_states
/joy
/joy_priority
/joy_vel
/key_vel
/marker
/marker_vel
/mobile_base_controller/cmd_vel_unstamped
/nav_vel
/odom
/parameter_events
/pause_navigation
/performance_metrics
/phone_vel
/robot_description
/rosout
/rviz_joy_vel
/servoing_cmd_vel
/stop_closing_loop
/tab_vel
/tf
/tf_static
/torso_controller/joint_trajectory
```

Comment: Can you add the output of ros2 topic list in case it doesn't match the list you have above? FWIW, I looked at the github page and wasn't able to find the referenced merge request in the CHANGELOG. The CHANGELOG references merge request robots/tiago_simulation!58 but I couldn't find that with google.

Comment: here you go, as for me the only thing I found was https://gitlab.uni-koblenz.de/robbie/tiago_simulation/-/blob/685c5550b6d509d575cc4e949395e60da406019e/tiago_2dnav_gazebo/CHANGELOG.rst but how could I fix this ? I updated everything

Comment: Have you reviewed the logs or the text sent to the terminal at start to see if there are errors or warnings generated on start of the many nodes? IIRC, both the scan and image are being dealt with in the same launch, and maybe that launch is failing(or not running).

Comment: there was, but I rebuilt everything, these errors disapeared, what logs can I check ?